# How do I make a mongoose find request where I am trying to find a document that contains all the tags in the query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

How do i make a mongoose find request to find something based on a inner field that has all of what is in the query. Example:

```
const query = [ "Power", "Logic" ]
const results = documents.filter(schematic => schematic.tags.filter(tag => query.includes(tag).length == query.length)
```

I am trying to make a tag system where you can search for schematics that contain certain tags, I am wondering how I would make a request that searches for a schematic that contains all of the tags in the query which is a array of the names of the tags and the tags on a schematic are also a array of objects where element.name is the tags name.

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Uk0l9lPNtMk) what are you looking for?

Comment: no, something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/so4UEfBIL-E)? And I am trying to find a document that matches all the tags in a query.

Comment: Then, something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d9dmji0Vlcl)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $all operator - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/

```
db.collection.find({'element.name': {$all: [ "Power", "Logic" ]}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.find({
  name: { $in: query }
})
```